# HTTP status code 500 (internal server error) while loading a JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat6

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<body>
<h:form><center>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Login: " />
        <h:inputText value="#{usBusiness.user.login}"/>
        <h:outputText value="mot de passe:" />
        <h:inpuText value="#{usBusiness.user.pwd}" />
        <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{usBusiness.user.connecter}" value="connecter" />
        <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{usBusiness.user.connecter}" value="annuler" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</center></h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

After I tried to access the page I've got the following error:

```
There was an internal server error that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

The exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /authentification.xhtml @12,49 <h:inpuText> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inpuText
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:270)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:390)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:517)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In our community English is *de facto* the only used language. This time I translated your question, but next time either do it on your own, or refrain from posting a question at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you *made proper indentation* **and carefully read your error description** it would be very clear to you that the error is trivial: instead of the line

```
<h:inpuText value="#{usBusiness.user.pwd}" />
```

note: **inpuText**, it should be

```
<h:inputText value="#{usBusiness.user.pwd}" />
```

note: **inputText**, which is explicitly stated in the error description:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /authentification.xhtml @12,49 <h:inpuText> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inpuText
```

By the way, your usage of `<center>` tag is outdated. Nowadays it is not used at all, and all the styling is achieved by using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in one of the tags:

```
    <h:inpuText value="#{usBusiness.user.pwd}" />
```

should be

```
    <h:inputText value="#{usBusiness.user.pwd}" />
```